# Access to VBA Transfer Spreadsheet Visibility

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Hi before my code is working. Here it is:

```
Dim xl As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim baseLocation As String

   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Report_Query", baseLocation, True

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xl.Workbooks.Open(baseLocation)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)

    xlSheet.Name = tableName
    xlSheet.Columns("A:" & MyModule.outColLetterFromNumber(fSize + 2)).AutoFit

    xl.Visible = True
    xl.DisplayFullScreen = True
```

But now when I run it the excel is missing its ribbon. Image attached[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line `xl.DisplayFullScreen = True` displays Excel in full screen mode, similar to when you press `F11` in your web browser.

If you intend to maximize the window, try

```
Const xlMaximized as Long = -4137
xl.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Also, if you simply want to reset the Excel window to normal (by this I mean so the ribbon is showing etc.), in the Immidiate window of the VBE, type `Application.DisplayFullScreen = False`.